# Add a subview as a background to a Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar

I'm using a Navigation Controller in my application and I'm trying to make a progress bar as the background of my Navigation Bar. I made a subclass of UIView to make my progress bar, this works fine.

Now when I build my Navigation Bar Items, I add my progress bar as a SubView of my navigation bar, as well as 2 buttons. This works fine too!

The problem is when I click in a row of my tableview, this makes a segue to a View Controller, and when I click the "Back" button, my progress bar in now on top of the buttons in my Navigation Bar.

Here's the code where I setup the navigation bar items :

```
    let progressBar = ScrollProgress(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.width, height: self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.height + 20), section: nil)
    progressBar.tag = 10
    progressBar.pourcentage = 92

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.addSubview(progressBar)

    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton

    let favorisButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Bookmarks, target: revealViewController(), action: #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = favorisButton

    self.navigationItem.title = "Demo App"
```

You can see here that it works fine, the progress bar covers 92% of the width of my navigation bar, and is UNDER the buttons and title :

[image]

Then when I click on a row of my tableview, this performs the segue to another ViewController, it works fine :

[image]

When I click the back button (Retour), my progress bar appears on top...

[image]

I can't find out why the subviews order is changing. I tried to replace my subview to the correct index with `self.navigationController!.navigationBar.exchangeSubviewAtIndex`, it works but the title is flickering at the end of the transition (but the buttons are not flickering).

Is there another way to do this, or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Shot in the dark - have you tried doing `sendSubviewToBack` in the `viewWillAppear` method of that controller?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it sends my view behind the navigation bar background which is the first layer of the navigation bar subviews stack, so I don't see my progress bar at all.

Comment: Instead of adding it to the navigation bar, you could add it to the main view and pin it at the top. I know after iOS 7 the edges of the view controller can extend underneath the navigation bar, so if you make the navigation bar transparent it will work the same.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, it makes sense... didn't think about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try not just to add a progress bar, but to insert it into the very bottom of the navigation bar `insertSubview(view: UIView, at: Int)`. This worked for me.

`self.navigationController!.navigationBar.insertSubview(progressBar, at: 0)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Trying to do something similar but this doesn't work for me. The subview still covers the bar buttons and title.